# EntityFramework 5 Self Referencing One-To-Zero-Or-One Entity

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, self-reference

I have a problem with a Self-Referencing Code-First Entity. Our code is like this:

```
public class Contact
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("AssignedCompany")]
   public Guid? AssignedCompanyId { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("AssignedContacts")]
   public virtual Contact AssignedCompany { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("AssignedCompany")]
   public virtual ICollection<Contact> AssignedContacts { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to start a Add-Migration (EF 5), I got the following Errormessage that Add-Migration can´t find a Principalend between Contact and Contact.

What do I do wrong?
Does anybody know the answer?

Thanks a lot. Kind regards
Christian Maaß

Answer (score 0):

The InverseProperty Attribute should only be used when you have multiple relationships between classes.  You can solve your issue by removing all the InverseProperty attributes.

Do like so, and it will work:

```
[ForeignKey("AssignedCompany")]
public Guid? AssignedCompanyId { get; set; }

public virtual Contact AssignedCompany { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Contact> AssignedContacts { get; set; }
```